# How do I output the unique lines from a grep pattern match while ignoring other parts of the line?

Tags: files, grep, terminal, regular-expression

Suppose I have a file called `names.txt`, which contains a list of names and corresponding emails of people in the following format:

```
FName1 LName1 <random1@test.com>
FName2 LName2 <random2@test2.com>
FName3 LName3 <random3@test3.com>
FName4 <random1@some.com>
FName5 MName1 LName4 <something@test34.com>
FName1 LName1 <random01@asdf.com>
...
```

What I am trying to accomplish is to output all of the unique people, case-insensitively, based on name (i.e. ignoring email) from `names.txt`. So, the output would look like the following:

```
FName1 LName1
FName2 LName2 
FName3 LName3 
FName4 
FName5 MName1 LName4
```

Note that the same name can appear multiple times in the file and names can be a mix of lower case characters, upper case characters, numbers, etc. Examples of names that can appear would be: "JoHn sMitH JOnes", "StEve", or "RoB3rt Fro5t"

What I am struggling with is how to just output the unique names without the associated email. I am able to use `grep` to match the patterns I am looking to output by using the following:

```
grep -i "^[A-Za-z0-9]*[ ]*[A-Za-z0-9]*[ ]*[A-Za-z0-9]*" names.txt
```

However, I am unsure how to use these pattern results and output the unique names while leaving out the email part of each line. Is there some way I can use these `grep` results and send them as standard input into some other command? Any feedback or suggestion would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `awk`:

```
awk '
  {
    sub(/<.*/, "") # remove email address
    $1 = $1 # remove leading and trailing blanks, squeeze all sequences of blanks
            # into one space
    if (!seen[tolower($0)]++) print # print if not seen before
  }' < names.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

You can go the other way around. Ignore the emails:

```
cut -d'<' -f1 names.txt | sort -fu
```

That cuts the line at the `<` separator, and prints the first field, sorts (ignoring the case `-f`) and then keeps just the first one of names that only differ in their case (also ignoring the case with `-u`).

Comment: Yes @StéphaneChazelas, you're right. For some reason I tend to "spell out" that kind of pipes, even when I work with them myself. Added to the answer.